# how can you loop through multiple arrays parallel?

Tags: ruby

i have 4 arrays.

```
["one", "two", "three"]
["1", "2", "3"
["un", "deux", "trois"]
["ichi", "ni", "san"]
```

is it possible to concatenate each element in their respective arrays ?

so i end up with single lines of string like like

```
"one, 1, un, ichi"\n
"two,2, deux,ni"\n
```

and so on...

is it possible to do this in one loop ?

```
for i in (1..array1.count)

puts array1[i] + ", " + array2[i] + ", " + array3[i] + ", " + array4[i]

end
```

What happens when there might be **unpredictable number of arrays** & they are each **unequal size**?

Comment: There we go. I couldn't help it, got excited and just wrote the code myself to make sure I said it right. Enjoy. Working code below (except for trailing commas but you can get rid of them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you know that they were all the same length:

```
(0...array1.length).each{|i|puts array1[i] + ", " + array2[i] + ", " + array3[i] + ", " + array4[i]}
```

Edit: **The Following code works**

```
array1 = ["one", "two", "three"]
array2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
array3 = ["un", "deux", "trois"]
array4 = ["ichi", "ni", "san"]

(0...array1.length).each{|i| puts array1[i] + ", " + array2[i] + ", " + array3[i] + ", " + array4[i]}
```

Edit2: **what happens if you dont know how many arrays there will be?**

I would suggest making an array of arrays; a list of arrays. Make an array of arrays (essentially a 2D array but it can't be indexed like one) and with it print every line one by one for each array in the arrayList.

This code works:

```
array1 = ["one", "two", "three"]
array2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
array3 = ["un", "deux", "trois"]
array4 = ["ichi", "ni", "san"]

arrayList = []
arrayList.push(array1, array2, array3, array4)

p arrayList

(0...array1.length).each{|i|
    (0...arrayList.length).each{|j|
        print arrayList[j][i] + ", "
    }
    print "\n"
}
```

Comment: what happens if you dont know how many array there really is ?

Comment: Yes it does, i mentioned that in my comment above, using join is nicer.

Comment: yeah seems like no other short cut way to do this. i have a similar setup as this.

Comment: I don't really think this is the best way. There are ways to make the `zip` and `transpose` solutions work for you. It may take a little extra effort, but IMHO the code ends up a little cleaner looking.

Answer (score 5):

Easy:

```
a = [array1,array2,array3,array4] # or however many you have

puts a.transpose.map {|x| x.join(", ")}.join("\n")
```

This will work with any number of subarrays as long as they are all the same size (regardless of what that size is).

If the subarrays are different lengths, but it's OK to use the length of the first one, you can do this:

```
a[0].zip(*a[1..-1]).map {|x| x.join(", ")}.join("\n")
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. I like my `zip` solution more (because it's mine, and because it puts them in the right order the first time), but it's nice to know about `transpose`.

Comment: Zip is great for pairs of arrays. But it only works if you know at code-writing time how many arrays you have, whereas transpose takes the array of arrays whole, and thus doesn't care how big it is. The transpose way is slightly faster, too.

Comment: is it possible to make it still work even when array's are not all same size?

Comment: We can make them all the same length: `n = a.map { |i| i.length }.max; n.times { |i| a[i].concat([nil] * (n - a[i].length)) }` (this pads them all with `nil` values so we can safely transpose them).

Comment: In my sleep I realized how to make the zip version work on any number of arrays: the mighty *.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`Enumerable#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003138) to create an array of arrays. It will create an array where the first element is an array of the first elements of all the arrays you pass to it, and so on with the second, third, etc. Then go through this list and print each argument using [`Array#join`](http://Array#join). Something like:

```
a.zip(b, c, d).each do |l|
  puts l.join(", ")
end
```

EDIT: No, `zip` won't be very helpful as far as appending arrays goes. [glenn's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598483/how-can-you-loop-through-multiple-arrays-parallel/1598576#1598576) method is good for that. You can append to the end of a `zip`ped array, but it's not as easy:

```
e = a.zip(b, c)
e.length.times { |i| e[i].push(d[i]) }
```

Comment: what if you dont know how many arrays you are dealing with. 

can you "push" arrays to a .zip() in a loop ?

Comment: Disregard that first edit. My brain was not working properly.

Comment: @gqweg you can unpack an unknown number of arrays to the zip method... see edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ruby 1.9 maybe you can take advantage of external iterators, this will let you deal with any number of arrays:

```
array1 = ['one','two','three']
array2 = [1,2,3,4]
array3 = ['un','deux','trois']
array4 = ['ichi','ni','san']

def bundle(*enumerables)
  enumerators = enumerables.map{ |e| e.to_enum }
  loop { puts enumerators.map { |e| e.next }.join(', ') }
end

bundle(array1,array2,array3,array4)
```

produces:

```
one, 1, un, ichi
two, 2, deux, ni
three, 3, trois, san
```