# Create an array of another array subelements in one line

Tags: ruby, arrays

Like this

```
oldArray = [[a, b, c, d],[e, f, g, h]]
```

I need one line of code that will return a new array of, say, element 2 in each element of oldArray

```
newArray = coolLine(oldArray, 2)

newArray -> [c, g]
```

Answer (score 3):

This does element number 2:

```
oldArray.map { |a| a[2] }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I can't destroy the original array....

Comment: @cdnbcguy This does not destroy the original array.

Comment: Add ! to map if you want to destroy it someday ;) - like map!

Comment: Ouch. Ok that's it, I'm going to bed. Sorry everyone....

Answer (score 0):

Smells a little like homework, but you're looking for the `map` function.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

> 2nd element in each element of oldArray

```
oldArray = [[a, b, c, d],[e, f, g, h]]
newArray = coolLine(oldArray, 2)
newArray -> [c, g]
```

The thing you want can be achieved in many ways. Most common would be the `map` and `zip`.

The `map` function allows you to process the sequence and re-calculate any of its items to a new value:

```
arr = [ [ 1,2,3 ], %w{ a b c }, [ 10,20,30] ]

# proc will be called twice
# 'item' will first be [ 1,2,3 ] then %w{ a b c } and so on
result = arr.map{|item|
    item[1]
}
result -> 2, then 'b', then 20
```

So, creating your "coolLine" seems pretty straightforward.

However, depending on other things, the [zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) may turn out to be even better. Zip takes N sequences and enumerates them sequentially returning Nth element from all at once. Why, that's almost exactly what you asked for:

```
arr = [ [ 1,2,3 ], %w{ a b c }, [ 10,20,30] ]

zipped = arr[0].zip(*arr[1..-1)

zipped -> [ [1,'a',10], [2,'b',20], [3,'c',30] ]
```

Or, of you don't like the [0]/*[1..-1] trick, you can easily write your own 'cleaner zip' like in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1601250/717732