# Concatenating parallel arrays Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, json

Basically the same question as [how can you loop through multiple arrays parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598483/how-can-you-loop-through-multiple-arrays-parallel) but using jQuery to put together an html page.

I have a set of three parallel objects with arrays. (Which could become a 2d array).

```
{"images":["Bellevue\/images\/1.jpg","Redmond\/images\/1.jpg","Seattle\/images\/1.jpg"],
"links":["Bellevue\/2.shtml","Redmond\/3.shtml","Seattle\/1.shtml"],
"projects":["Bellevue","Redmond","Seattle"]}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure how to get them to populate my page without them running into each other.

So can I store data from $.each functions like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'populate.php',
dataType: 'json',
async: false,
data: "{'images','links','projects'}",
success: function(data, object) {
   $.each(data.images, function(index, value) {
      // maybe something like?: $images = $('.footer').prepend('<img src="'+value+'" />')
   });
   $.each(data.links, function(index, value) {
      $('.footer').prepend('<a>'+value+'</a>')
   });
   $.each(data.projects, function(index, value) {
      $('.footer').prepend('<a>'+value+'</a>')
   });
   }
});
});
```

And create their respective iterations in some html for each parallel object in the arrays:

```
$('body').append('<div class="wrap"><div class="box"><div class="boxInner"><a href="'+data.links+'"><img src="'+data.images+'"/></a><div class="titleBox">'+data.projects+'</div></div></div>');
```

Or am I trying to do this completely wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build the markup in the loop, using the index to access the arrays values that correspond with the currently iterated array, and after it's all built you insert it into the DOM

```
var html = $([]);

$.each(data.images, function(index, value) {
  var wrap  = $('<div />', {'class' : 'wrap'}),
      box   = $('<div />', {'class' : 'box'}),
      inner = $('<div />', {'class' : 'boxInner'}),
      a     = $('<a />',   {href : data.links[index]}),
      img   = $('<img />', {src : value}),
      title = $('<div />', {'class' : 'titleBox', text : data.projects[index]});

  html = html.add(wrap.append(box.append(boxInner.append(a.append(img), title))));
});

$('body').append(html);
```

Comment: I could kiss you! Works great!